# How to mock a promise in jest angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

Here is the method I have:

```
  async signMessage(xml, mbo): Promise<any> {
    try {
      const isSignatureAppAlive = await this.pingDigitalSignatureApp().toPromise();
 
      if (isSignatureAppAlive.alive) {
        try {
          this.signedMsg = await this.getSignedMsg(xml, mbo).toPromise();
          return this.signedMsg;
        } catch (er) {
          return this.handleSignatureAppErrorCodes(er.error.errorCode);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      this.showSignatureInfoModal();
      return this.handleError({ message: 'empty' });
    }
  }
```

```
getSignedMsg(msg, mbo): Observable<any> {
    this.signDocument.title = '';
    this.signDocument.content = btoa(msg);
    this.signDocument.contentType = 'application/xml';
    this.signDocument.uriOrIdToSign = '';

    this.postParam.certificateAlias = mbo;
    this.postParam.digestAlgorithm = 'SHA1';
    this.postParam.documents = [];
    this.postParam.documents.push(this.signDocument);
    this.postParam.signingMethod = 'xmldsig';
    this.postParam.envelopingMethod = 'enveloped';

    return this.http.post<any>(SERVICE_URL + 'sign', this.postParam, httpOptions).pipe();
  }
```

My test covers catching error:

```
   service.signMessage('xml', 'mbo').catch((errCode) => {
     expect(errCode).toBe('empty');
     done();
   });
 });
```

What logic do I need to add in order to cover if statement? Do I have to mock a Promise? Not sure what to do here. I tried this:

```
  it('signMessage', async (done) => {
    const spy = spyOn(service, 'pingDigitalSignatureApp').and.returnValue(
      new Promise((resolve) => resolve('someVal')),
    );
    service.pingDigitalSignatureApp();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    done();
  });
```

Nothing happens, in a sense that test doesn't go to if statement. Advice appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happens? Also you should not use `done` when you are using an `async` function

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing a `.toPromise()` on the method in question, you need to return an `Observable` and not a promise. And yes, you need to return an object where the `if` condition will be satisfied.

Try this:

```
// we don't need done
it('signMessage', async () => {
    // return an observable
    const spy = spyOn(service, 'pingDigitalSignatureApp').and.returnValue(
      of({ alive: true } as any) 
    );
    // make getSignedMsg return hello
    spyOn(service, 'getSignedMsg').and.returnValue(of('hello'));
    // await for the result
    const result = await service.pingDigitalSignatureApp();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // expect it to go inside of the if and it returned hello
    expect(result).toBe('hello');
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I see that getSignedMsg returns an observable, so it should expect that type, instead of string. I added the getSignedMsg in initial post. However, if I console.log isSignatureAppAlive, it gives me undefined, so it never reaches if.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure, it should be working.

Comment: No worries, thank you. We decided to get back to this a bit later. I will post a solution when we get to it. :)